# Openstack Devstack Magnum: Creating stack times out, check stack fails

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-heat

I'm currently experimenting with Openstack/Devstack using heat and magnum all on the victoria release. However when I create a new stack I see the master instance being created but heat keeps it on Create In Progress and this till it times out. When I manually do a check stack it returns: Resource CHECK failed: ['The resource kube_masters is already being updated.']. 'CHECK' not fully supported (see resources).
I'll include my local.conf

```
[[local|localrc]]

HOST_IP=192.168.0.4
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.0.5,end=192.168.0.49
ADMIN_PASSWORD=nomoresecret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=stackdb
RABBIT_PASSWORD=stackqueue
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
LOGDAYS=2

SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

enable_plugin devstack-plugin-container https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack-plugin-container
enable_plugin heat https://opendev.org/openstack/heat stable/victoria
enable_plugin heat-dashboard https://opendev.org/openstack/heat-dashboard stable/victoria
enable_plugin magnum https://opendev.org/openstack/magnum stable/victoria
enable_plugin magnum-ui https://opendev.org/openstack/magnum-ui stable/victoria
enable_plugin octavia https://opendev.org/openstack/octavia stable/victoria
enable_plugin octavia-dashboard https://opendev.org/openstack/octavia-dashboard stable/victoria
```

Does any one have an idea what this could be.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "check stack"? How do you check it? While the [Magnum troubleshooting guide](https://docs.openstack.org/magnum/latest/admin/troubleshooting-guide.html) is incomplete, it probably contains the steps, at least initial steps, for tackling your problem.

Comment: Your cloud might not be connected to the internet. I wrote a series of Medium articles about Kubernetes on Devstack, [including Magnum](https://itnext.io/using-openstack-magnum-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-af8ec3cfbda5). It might help.